# Linker error when building Unity3D mobile project for iOS in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, linker

I recently updated my OSX to El Capitan and, because of an issue with my previous version of Unity (v 5.0.1 I believe), I was forced to update to the latest version (5.2.1f1). Now, when I build for iOS, I get the following error during the linking process:

> ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using the Soomla library for in-app purchases and social integration, as well as Parse for the online database. I believe at least one of these libraries could be responsible for this, since they both contain Facebook-related code. In any case, I can't figure out what I need to try next. Both plugins have been updated to their latest versions.

I attempted building with the *Mono2x* scripting backend first, as usual. Then, I tried changing it to *IL2CPP* and tried compiling for *armv7*, *arm64*, and the *Universal* architecture options. Nothing worked.

I also tried manually adding the FBSDKCoreKit framework file downloaded from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios. This also didn't work, except this time I got a slightly different error:

> ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit clang: error: linker command
>
> failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm not sure why it would say this when I explicitly add the framework into the Xcode project. Could anyone give me any insight?